# Unicode decode error when running HTTP server

Tags: python-3.x

I've got this traceback after executing this:

```
python -m http.server 8080
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lotarc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Lotarc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Lotarc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\server.py", line 1262, in <module>
    test(HandlerClass=handler_class, port=args.port, bind=args.bind)
  File "C:\Users\Lotarc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\server.py", line 1230, in test
    with ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass) as httpd:
  File "C:\Users\Lotarc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\Lotarc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\server.py", line 139, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Users\Lotarc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 676, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 7: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: What is your hostname; what's the output of `hostname -f`?

Comment: ```hostname -f``` won't execute it tells ```hostname -s``` isn't supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in locked hosts 127.0.0.1 ipv4 and ::1 ipv6 and changing windows name user has helped me at some point

Comment: What change did you make to the username?

Comment: I deleted ukrainian symbols from it